# How do I make a Django database query that has multiple filters?

Tags: python, json, django, http

I have a database of artists and paintings, and I want to query based on artist name and painting title. The titles are in a json file (the artist name comes from ajax) so I tried a loop.

```
def rest(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)
    artistname = data['artiste']
    with open('/static/top_paintings.json', 'r') as fb:
        top_paintings_dict = json.load(fb)

    response_data = []

    for painting in top_paintings_dict[artist_name]:
        filterargs = {'artist__contains': artistname, 'title__contains': painting}  
        response_data.append(serializers.serialize('json', Art.objects.filter(**filterargs)))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

It does not return a list of objects like I need, just some ugly double-serialized json data that does no good for anyone.

```
   ["[{\"fields\": {\"artist\": \"Leonardo da Vinci\", \"link\": \"https://trove2.storage.googleapis.com/leonardo-da-vinci/the-madonna-of-the-carnation.jpg\", \"title\": \"The Madonna of the Carnation\"}, \"model\": \"serve.art\", \"pk\": 63091}]",
```

This handler works and returns every painting I have for an artist.

```
def rest(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)
    artistname = data['artiste']
    response_data = serializers.serialize("json", Art.objects.filter(artist__contains=artistname))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

I just need to filter my query by title as well as by artist.

Comment: You're building a Python list of serializations, then serializing that list. Do you want your json to be a list of lists of serialized objects, or just one list of objects?

Comment: I want one list of objects. I could not get the `Art.objects.filter()` to query one artist name and a list of painting titles, but that is what I need. One artist, multiple paintings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inYour problem is that you are serializing the data to json twice - once with `serializers.serialize` and then once more with `json.dumps`.

I don't know the specifics of your application, but can chain filters in django. So I would go with your second approach and just replace the line

```
response_data = serializers.serialize("json", Art.objects.filter(artist__contains=artistname))
```

with

```
response_data = serializers.serialize("json", Art.objects.filter(artist__contains=artistname).filter(title__in=paintings))
```

Check the [queryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: I have multiple titles, not just one title. Your code would only return one object. I already tried to make a list of serialized objects and it doesn't give me anything useful.

Comment: That'll work for exact title matches - if you need `__contains` on the painting title, I think my answer is closer. But this one is preferable if exact title match is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do this for a `__contains` search on painting title would be to use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to `or` together all your possible painting names:

```
from operator import or_

def rest(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)
    artistname = data['artiste']
    with open('/static/top_paintings.json', 'r') as fb:
        top_paintings_dict = json.load(fb)

    title_filters = reduce(or_, (Q(title__contains=painting) for painting in top_paintings_dict[artist_name]))
    paintings = Art.objects.filter(title_filters, artist__contains=artist_name)
```

That'll get you a queryset of paintings. I suspect your double serialization is not correct, but it seems you're happy with it in the single artist name case so I'll leave that up to you.

The `reduce` call here is a way to build up the result of `|`ing together multiple `Q` objects - `operator.or_` is a functional handle for `|`, and then I'm using a generator expression to create a `Q` object for each painting name.

Comment: I'm not double-serializing it anymore.

Comment: Your answer contains some advanced methods that I need to learn.

Comment: `Q` objects are worth learning. You can skip `reduce` and `operator.or_` if you're not sure about them and just use `title_filters = Q(title__contains=top_paintings_dict[artist_name][0]); for painting in top_paintings_dict[artist_name][1:]: title_filters = title_filters | Q(title__contains=painting)`